# compile linux kernel on mac os x: clang error

Tags: eclipse, macos, clang

I Wanna compile the linux kernel 2.6 on my mac osx 10.10, so I followed the steps: [Linux kernel development and debugging using Eclipse CDT.](http://www.sw-at.com/blog/2011/02/11/linux-kernel-development-and-debugging-using-eclipse-cdt/)

But I came across the problem at the step: make menuconfig O=/mnt/build/linux-2.6.
And the error is below, what should I do?

```
GEN     /mnt/build/linux-2.6/Makefile
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_COLS", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_LINES", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_acs_map", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _print_arrows in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _draw_box in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      ...
  "_cbreak", referenced from:
      _reset_dialog in util.o
  "_delwin", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_doupdate", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _end_dialog in util.o
  "_flash", referenced from:
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
  "_getcurx", referenced from:
      _print_autowrap in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _print_line in textbox.o
      _print_arrows in menubox.o
  "_getcury", referenced from:
      _print_autowrap in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _print_line in textbox.o
      _print_arrows in menubox.o
  "_getmaxx", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_getmaxy", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _attr_clear in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
      ...
  "_has_colors", referenced from:
      _init_dialog in util.o
      _draw_shadow in util.o
  "_init_pair", referenced from:
      _init_dialog in util.o
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _reset_dialog in util.o
  "_keypad", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _reset_dialog in util.o
      _on_key_esc in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
      ...
  "_newwin", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_nodelay", referenced from:
      _on_key_esc in util.o
  "_noecho", referenced from:
      _reset_dialog in util.o
  "_scrollok", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_start_color", referenced from:
      _init_dialog in util.o
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _reset_dialog in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
      ...
  "_subwin", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_ungetch", referenced from:
      _on_key_esc in util.o
  "_waddch", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _print_arrows in checklist.o
      _attr_clear in util.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _print_title in util.o
      _print_button in util.o
      ...
  "_waddnstr", referenced from:
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _print_arrows in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _print_title in util.o
      _print_autowrap in util.o
      _print_button in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      ...
  "_wattrset", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _print_arrows in checklist.o
      _attr_clear in util.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _print_title in util.o
      _print_button in util.o
      ...
  "_wbkgdset", referenced from:
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_wclrtoeol", referenced from:
      _print_line in textbox.o
      _do_print_item in menubox.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _on_key_esc in util.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_winch", referenced from:
      _draw_shadow in util.o
  "_wmove", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _print_arrows in checklist.o
      _attr_clear in util.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _print_title in util.o
      _print_autowrap in util.o
      ...
  "_wnoutrefresh", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_clear in util.o
      _draw_shadow in util.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_wprintw", referenced from:
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
  "_wrefresh", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _print_item in checklist.o
      _dialog_inputbox in inputbox.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _refresh_text_box in textbox.o
      _dialog_yesno in yesno.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
      ...
  "_wscrl", referenced from:
      _dialog_checklist in checklist.o
      _dialog_textbox in textbox.o
      _dialog_menu in menubox.o
  "_wtouchln", referenced from:
      _attr_clear in util.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

Comment: The errrors looks like ld64 errors. Are you sure you are using the right compiler and linker? The Mac OS X compiler and linker won't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: I have already installed new version gcc 5.2.0 via brew. And alias gcc='gcc-5', which is in /usr/local/bin. Normally I compile a C program using gcc, it indeed is my installed one. So how can I make use of gcc complier and linker in this condition, not the ones of Mac OS X.

Comment: You can't compile the Linux kernel on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, you can compile Linux kernel on Mac OS X. I'm successfully compiling the kernel for a custom board, but still I cannot run `make menuconfig` because of the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the Linux Kernel os OSX, but you first have to install ncurses.  You can try to use brew to install it, but I like installing from source, so I found this:

```
$ curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
$ cd ./ncurses-5.9
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
  --without-cxx --without-cxx-binding --without-ada --without-progs --without-curses-h \
  --with-shared --without-debug \
  --enable-widec --enable-const --enable-ext-colors --enable-sigwinch --enable-wgetch-events \
&& make
$ sudo make install
```

You will probably also need --enable-pc-files , otherwise pkg-config won't see it (assuming you have pkg-config installed).  Once that's done, you still have a problem:  pkg-config reports the install location as something like "/usr/local/include/ncursesw" (which is where it is, so pkg-config is correct), but the internal include files all have

> `<ncursesw/xxx.h>`

in them (at least ncurses.h and the unctrl.h file).  This poses a catch-22 because linux uses some scripts that want to provide the pkg-config info, which is great, but then when the script (specifically /your-path-to-src/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh) wants to compile a test program, it fails because pkg-config doesn't report "/usr/local/include" and "ncursesw/ncurses.h" appropriately back to the lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh script.  This causes a failure on macos. To fix this, I changed the ncurses includes to read:

> `<xxx.h>`

I know this question is a little old, but I wanted to post SOMETHING as it took me a while to ferret this out.

Answer (score 0):

To run `make menuconfig` on OSX, install below packages

```
brew install pkg-config ncurses
```

And add below line in your shell path.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
```